# Index Created but doesn't speed-up on retrieval process

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have created table as bellow

```
create table T1(num varchar2(20))
```

then I inserted 3 lac numbers in above table so now it looks like below

```
num
1
2
3
.
.
300000
```

Now if I do

```
select * from T1
```

then it takes 1min 15sec to completely fetch the records and as I created index on column `num` and if I use below query then it should be faster to fetch 3 lac records but it takes also 1min15sec for fetch the records

```
select * from T1 where num between '1' and '300000'
```

So how the index has improved my retrieval process?

Comment: I hope you're not actually trying to select a continuous range of numbers stored as character here. This query would not return any values that start with '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', and '9'. (E.g. '4', '82', '598', '9999', etc.).

Comment: @PatrickMarchand So how to select that continous range of numbers in this scenario..can u give some query to do this

Comment: If you want the data to behave as numbers, you either store them as NUMBER(p,s) or you do an on-the-fly conversion: WHERE TO_NUMBER(num) BETWEEN 1 AND 300000 (no quotes). The catch here is that if somewhere in the data you have a letter (possible given the datatype of VARCHAR2) then the query can fail.

Comment: oh, one more thing. Since the function call TO_NUMBER() will not use any indexes on the NUM column if you have a really big table, you may consider a function-based index on TO_NUMBER(num)... but I'd prefer just storing the data using a NUMBER datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index does not improve the retrieval process when you are trying to fetch all rows.

The index makes it possible to find a subset of rows much more quickly.

Comment: Baba, if this is the correct answer, please mark it correct by clicking the check mark to the left of it, thanks!

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct in general. An index can speed up a query that returns all rows from a table when it spans the SELECT list (all columns selected are contained in the index). Here fetching from the index can be faster to retrieve all rows than it is from the base table as the index is narrower -- less blocks to read.

Answer (score 1):

An index can help if you want to retrieve a few rows from a large table. But since you retrieve all rows and since your index contains all the columns of your table, it won't speed up the query.

Furthermore, you don't tell us what tool you use to retrieve the data. I guess you use SQL Developer or Toad. So what you measure is the time it takes SQL Developer or Toad to store 300,000 rows in memory in such a way that they can be easily displayed on screen in a scrollable table. You aren't really measuring how long it takes to retrieve them.

Comment: @juergen i am using PLSQL Developer version 9 which show me a time taken to fetch rows THanx for advice

Answer (score 0):

To get a test of the effects of having an index in place you might want to try a query such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM T1
  WHERE NUM IN ('288888', '188888', '88888')
```

both with with the index in place, and again after removing the index.  You should also collect statistics on the table prior to running the query with the index in place or you may still get a query which performs a full table scan.  Share and enjoy.